# Choosing the right logical identities for simplifying an expression

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am having a little tough time deciding which logical identities to use for proving that
`(p ∧ ~q) ∨ (p ∧ q) ≡ p`

I have tried a couple of things but I seem to be getting back the same logical expression that I try to simplify over and over again.

Comment: Start with the distributive property.

Comment: If you edit what you've tried into your question I can explain what you're doing wrong. Otherwise, all I can do is give you a vague hint about conjoining a theorem with a wff

Answer (score 0):

Isolating one variable and you can get the following:

$1.\space (p \land \lnot q)\lor(p \land q) \space \text{, Given.}\\ 
2. \space (p \lor (p \land q)) \land (\lnot q \lor (p \land q)) \space \text{, Distributive}\\
3. \space p \land (\lnot q \lor (p \land q)) \space \text{, Absorption}\\
4. \space p \land (\lnot q\lor p) \land (\lnot q \lor q) \space \text{, Distributive}\\
5 \space p \land (\lnot q \lor p) \land T \space \text{, Negation}\\
6. \space p \land (\lnot q \lor p) \space \text{, Identity}\\
7. p\space \text{, Absorption} \\ \square$

Comment: How are you getting $1 \to 2$?

Comment: You're right. This isn't valid. Updating my answer.

Comment: Also, you might try using the other distributive property to show $p \land (q \lor \neg q)$ is equivalent to $(p \land q) \lor (p \land \neg q)$.

Comment: Very clever! That eliminates a lot of extra steps.